# ¿Cómo hacer responsive tarjetas ubicadas en el footer de la página?

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive, card

Estoy trabajando en el footer de la página y coloqué unas tarjetas de Bootstrap separadas con CSS(lo que pienso que puede ser uno de los errores) y me gustaría que fueran responsive lo cual cumplen esa función pero aparecen desordenadas por la página y el texto de las mismas mantiene un tamaño fijo.

**¿Cómo puedo hacer qué mantengan ese espacio entre tarjetas en línea horizontal pero que al momento de cambiar las dimensiones de la pantalla estas mismas aparezcan una debajo de la otra y su fuente acompañe al tamaño de la tarjeta?**

- Corran el ejemplo en pantalla completa para qué puedan apreciar mejor las posiciones de las tarjetas.

Quedo atento a sus sugerencias!!

```css
.navbar .header-2 {
  grid-area: navbar;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 73px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  box-sizing: initial;
  border-left: 5px solid #145D56;
  border-right: 4px solid #EEE7CE;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #145D56;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 2300;
}

.navbar .header-2.active {
  width: 230px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99.9%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 79px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  transition: 0s;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active {
  background: #EEE7CE;
  transition: 0s;
  height: 55px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(1),
.header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 190%;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EEE7CE;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0s;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 62px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 7px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 65px;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: .95em;
}

.navbar .toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  left: 24px;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2300;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nameUser {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 22px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 32px;
}

.toggle.active {
  left: 190px;
}

.toggle ion-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 34px;
  display: none;
}

.toggle ion-icon.open,
.toggle.active ion-icon.close {
  display: block;
  color: #FFC728;
}

.toggle ion-icon.close,
.toggle.active ion-icon.open {
  display: none;
}

.footer .block-item1 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  background-color: #EEE7CE;
  color: #145d56;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  margin-left: 8rem;
}

.footer .block-item2 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  background-color: #EEE7CE;
  color: #145d56;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  margin-left: 8rem;
}

.footer .block-item3 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  background-color: #EEE7CE;
  color: #145d56;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 8rem;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  margin-inline-end: 4%;
}

.footer .sub-head {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.footer .desc {
  color: #1D2A35;
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.692);
  font-weight: 450;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body class="grid-container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="header-2">
      <ul>
        <p class="nameUser">Menú</p>
        <li class="list">
          <b></b>
          <b></b>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon">
                            <i class="uil uil-estate"></i>
                        </span>
            <span class="title">Inicio</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
          <b></b>
          <b></b>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon">
                            <i class="uil uil-books"></i>
                        </span>
            <span href="#" class="title">Explorar Libros</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list active">
          <b></b>
          <b></b>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon">
                            <i class="uil uil-question-circle"></i>
                        </span>
            <span href="#" class="title">Acerca de</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <hr style="border: 2px solid #EEE7CE; border-radius: 2px; opacity: 1; width: 90%; margin-left: -2%; box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle">
      <ion-icon name="menu-outline" class="open"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="close-outline" class="close"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!----------- PIE DE PÁGINA ----------->
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="block-item1 ">
      <i class="uil uil-envelope" style="font-size: 250%; color: #145D56;"></i>
      <div class="sub-head">Email</div>
      <a href="mailto:bibliotecae.dussel2020@gmail.com" class="desc" style="font-size: 75%;">bibliotecae@gmail.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block-item2">
      <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 250%; color: #FFC728;"></i>
      <div class="sub-head">Horarios</div>
      <a href="aboutOn" class="desc" style="font-size: 75%;">Horarios de atención</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block-item3">
      <i class="uil uil-location-point" style="font-size: 250%; color: #D90E40;"></i>
      <div class="sub-head">Visitanos</div>
      <a href="Ubicación" class="desc" style="font-size: 75%;">Ubicación Biblioteca</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap trae clases predefinidas para facilitar la maquetación y un sistema de grilla super potente. Te sugiero darle una repasada a la [documentación oficial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/) para que no te hagas líos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a quitar todos los espaciados que haces a cada item (que son esos cuadros amarillos). Haciendo esto, veo que los 3 items tienen los mismos estilos, entonces, reduciendo el código, quedaría así:

```
.footer .block-item1,
.footer .block-item2,
.footer .block-item3 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  background-color: #EEE7CE;
  color: #145d56;
  text-align: center;
  width: 140px; /* le doy un ancho fijo a los items para evitar que el texto de adentro se sobresalga */
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  margin: 10px; /* le doy un margin a los 4 lados para evitar que los items estén uno encima del otro */
}
```

Ahora faltaría hacer flexible a tu clase `footer` para que los items estén perfectamente responsivos. Entonces, coloqué estas clases de bootstrap:

```
<footer class="footer d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <!-- tus 3 items -->
</footer>
```

En donde básicamente indico que los items serán flexibles con `d-flex`, luego con `flex-sm-row` indico que los elementos estarán posicionados en una fila hasta superar el ancho de `sm`, una vez supere el ancho, estarán en columnas, por el `flex-column`. Luego con `justify-content-between` indico que los elementos tendrán espacios entre sí ocupando todo el ancho del contenedor `footer`, y alíneo los items en el centro con `align-items-center`.

Por cierto, hasta aquí, tu contenedor `footer` ocupará todo el ancho de la pantalla, estando detrás de tu barra de navegación, entonces le di un `margin` a la izquierda y derecha para que esto no ocurra:

```
.footer {
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Obteniendo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código final:

```css
.navbar .header-2 {
  grid-area: navbar;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 73px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  box-sizing: initial;
  border-left: 5px solid #145D56;
  border-right: 4px solid #EEE7CE;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #145D56;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 2300;
}

.navbar .header-2.active {
  width: 230px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99.9%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 79px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  transition: 0s;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active {
  background: #EEE7CE;
  transition: 0s;
  height: 55px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(1),
.header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 190%;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EEE7CE;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0s;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 62px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 7px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 65px;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: .95em;
}

.navbar .toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  left: 24px;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2300;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nameUser {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 22px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 32px;
}

.toggle.active {
  left: 190px;
}

.toggle ion-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 34px;
  display: none;
}

.toggle ion-icon.open,
.toggle.active ion-icon.close {
  display: block;
  color: #FFC728;
}

.toggle ion-icon.close,
.toggle.active ion-icon.open {
  display: none;
}

.footer {
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.footer .block-item1,
.footer .block-item2,
.footer .block-item3 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  background-color: #EEE7CE;
  color: #145d56;
  text-align: center;
  width: 140px; /* le doy un ancho fijo a los items para evitar que el texto de adentro se sobresalga */
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  margin: 10px; /* le doy un margin a los 4 lados para evitar que los items estén uno encima del otro */
}

.footer .sub-head {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.footer .desc {
  color: #1D2A35;
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.692);
  font-weight: 450;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body class="grid-container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="header-2">
        <ul>
          <p class="nameUser">Menú</p>
          <li class="list">
            <b></b>
            <b></b>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="uil uil-estate"></i>
              </span>
              <span class="title">Inicio</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list">
            <b></b>
            <b></b>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="uil uil-books"></i>
              </span>
              <span href="#" class="title">Explorar Libros</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list active">
            <b></b>
            <b></b>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="uil uil-question-circle"></i>
              </span>
              <span href="#" class="title">Acerca de</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <hr style="border: 2px solid #EEE7CE; border-radius: 2px; opacity: 1; width: 90%; margin-left: -2%; box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);">
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="toggle">
        <ion-icon name="menu-outline" class="open"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="close-outline" class="close"></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!----------- PIE DE PÁGINA ----------->
    <footer class="footer d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <div class="block-item1">
        <i class="uil uil-envelope" style="font-size: 250%; color: #145D56;"></i>
        <div class="sub-head">Email</div>
        <a href="mailto:bibliotecae.dussel2020@gmail.com" class="desc" style="font-size: 75%;">bibliotecae@gmail.com</a>
      </div>
      <div class="block-item2">
        <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 250%; color: #FFC728;"></i>
        <div class="sub-head">Horarios</div>
        <a href="aboutOn" class="desc" style="font-size: 75%;">Horarios de atención</a>
      </div>
      <div class="block-item3">
        <i class="uil uil-location-point" style="font-size: 250%; color: #D90E40;"></i>
        <div class="sub-head">Visitanos</div>
        <a href="Ubicación" class="desc" style="font-size: 75%;">Ubicación Biblioteca</a>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**este enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/mdGwRmr).

Comment: Excelente amigo, me sirve de mucha ayuda tú respuesta ya qué todo lo que necesitaba. Gracias y saludos!!

Comment: Amigo @Cris223511.dev podrías revisar mi nueva pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/585756/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-para-qu%c3%a9-el-footer-ocupe-todo-el-ancho-del-pie-de-p%c3%a1gina  Porqué utilice tú código de tarjetas responsives pero tuve unos inconvenientes al querer adaptarlo al diseño que traía podría echarle un vistazo?  Cuando tengas tiempo, es sin apuro