# ¿Cómo hacer para qué el footer ocupe todo el ancho del pie de página?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Quiero mantener un estilo para los elementos del pie de página(imagen de ejemplo abajo) las tarjetas las posicioné con CSS pero hoy las hice responsives con la ayuda con un compañero del foro pero ahora quedaron un poco desordenados los elementos.

Me gustaría qué el fondo del footer ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla siguiendo de guía la imagen

¿Qué debería modificar en el código del pie de página lograr nuevamente el resultado del ejemplo gráfico y siga actuando responsive?

Quedo atento a sus respuestas!!

Imagen de ejemplo y guía de diseño
[image: Imagen]

```css
.navbar .header-2 {
  grid-area: navbar;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 73px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  box-sizing: initial;
  border-left: 5px solid #145D56;
  border-right: 4px solid #EEE7CE;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #145D56;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 2300;
}

.navbar .header-2.active {
  width: 230px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99.9%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 79px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  transition: 0s;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active {
  background: #EEE7CE;
  transition: 0s;
  height: 55px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(1),
.header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 190%;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EEE7CE;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0s;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 62px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 7px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 65px;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: .95em;
}

.navbar .toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  left: 24px;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2300;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nameUser {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 22px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 32px;
}

.toggle.active {
  left: 190px;
}

.toggle ion-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 34px;
  display: none;
}

.toggle ion-icon.open,
.toggle.active ion-icon.close {
  display: block;
  color: #FFC728;
}

.toggle ion-icon.close,
.toggle.active ion-icon.open {
  display: none;
}






/* ----------- PIE DE PÁGINA ----------- */

.footer {
  background-color: #232d35;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.footer .block-item1,
.footer .block-item2,
.footer .block-item3 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  background-color: #EEE7CE;
  color: #145d56;
  text-align: center;
  width: 190px;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.footer .sub-head {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.footer .desc {
  color: #1D2A35;
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.692);
  font-weight: 450;
}

.footer .desc:hover {
  color: #2a5be0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body class="grid-container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="header-2">
      <ul>
        <p class="nameUser">Menú</p>
        <li class="list">
          <b></b>
          <b></b>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon">
                            <i class="uil uil-estate"></i>
                        </span>
            <span class="title">Inicio</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
          <b></b>
          <b></b>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon">
                            <i class="uil uil-books"></i>
                        </span>
            <span href="#" class="title">Explorar Libros</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list active">
          <b></b>
          <b></b>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="icon">
                            <i class="uil uil-question-circle"></i>
                        </span>
            <span href="aboutOn" class="title">Acerca de</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <hr style="border: 2px solid #EEE7CE; border-radius: 2px; opacity: 1; width: 90%; margin-left: -2%; box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle">
      <ion-icon name="menu-outline" class="open"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="close-outline" class="close"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!----------- PIE DE PÁGINA ----------->
  <footer class="footer d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="block-item1">
      <i class="uil uil-envelope" style="font-size: 250%; color: #145D56;"></i>
      <div class="sub-head">Email</div>
      <a href="mailto:bibliotecae.public2020@gmail.com" class="desc" style="font-size: 60%;">bibliotecae.public2020@gmail.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block-item2">
      <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 250%; color: #f5b914;"></i>
      <div class="sub-head">Horarios</div>
      <a href="/aboutOn" class="desc" style="font-size: 75%;">Horarios de atención</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block-item3">
      <i class="uil uil-location-point" style="font-size: 250%; color: #D90E40;"></i>
      <div class="sub-head">Visitanos</div>
      <a href="ubicacion" class="desc" style="font-size: 75%;">Ubicación Biblioteca</a>
    </div>

    <hr class="bg-danger border-2 border-top border-color">
    <div class="pages">
      <a href="/" class="title1">Inicio |</a>
      <a href="explorarLibros" class="title2">Explorar Libros |</a>
      <a href="aboutOn" class="title3">Acerca de</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #3b5998; border-color: #00000000;
            margin-left: 50%; border-radius: 90%;" href="#!" role="button"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
    </div>

    <hr class="bg-danger border-2 border-top border-color">
  </footer>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede que estas clases:

```html
<div class="footer d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-between align-items-center">
```

Esta afectando a tus items y a tu sección de redes sociales, es por eso que al principio verás a tus elementos en una fila, uno al lado del otro. La solución sería separar tus elementos, ya que solo nos importa que éstas clases afecte a los items y no a tus redes sociales, entonces, hice esta estructura:

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="items d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <!-- tus items -->
  </div>
  <hr class="bg-danger border-2 border-top border-color">
  <div class="pages">
    <!-- tus redes -->
  </div>
</footer>
```

Si te das cuenta, todas las clases lo moví en el nuevo contenedor que creé, encerrando únicamente a tus items, así ya no afectaría a tus redes sociales de abajo.

También, modifiqué un poco el CSS, indicando que el `footer` ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla y que el contenedor de los items sí tenga un espaciado a la izquierda para que tus items no estén detrás de tu navegador lateral:

```
.footer {
  background-color: #232d35;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%; /* el footer ocupará todo el ancho de la pantalla */
}

.footer .pages {
    margin-left: 90px; /* y el contenedor de los items tendrán un espaciado a la izquierda */
}
```

Así solucionarías el problema de tus items.

---

Plus: Intenté hacer el diseño de tus redes sociales, lo que hice fue agregar estas clases al div `pages`:

```
<div class="pages d-flex justify-content-between p-4 pt-0 pb-0">
  <!-- tus redes -->
</div>
```

En donde indico que el contenido de adentro será flexible con `d-flex`, tendrán espacios entre ellos ocupando todo el ancho del contenedor con `justify-content-between` y hago espacios a la izquierda y derecha con `p-4 pt-0 pb-0`.

Código final:

```css
.navbar .header-2 {
  grid-area: navbar;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 73px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  box-sizing: initial;
  border-left: 5px solid #145D56;
  border-right: 4px solid #EEE7CE;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #145D56;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 2300;
}

.navbar .header-2.active {
  width: 230px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99.9%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 79px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
  transition: 0s;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active {
  background: #EEE7CE;
  transition: 0s;
  height: 55px;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE7CE;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li b:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  background: #145D56;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(1),
.header-2 ul li.active b:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 190%;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EEE7CE;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li.active a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0s;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 62px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.navbar .header-2 ul li a .title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 7px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 65px;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: .95em;
}

.navbar .toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  left: 24px;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2300;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nameUser {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 22px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 32px;
}

.toggle.active {
  left: 190px;
}

.toggle ion-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 34px;
  display: none;
}

.toggle ion-icon.open,
.toggle.active ion-icon.close {
  display: block;
  color: #FFC728;
}

.toggle ion-icon.close,
.toggle.active ion-icon.open {
  display: none;
}






/* ----------- PIE DE PÁGINA ----------- */

.footer {
  background-color: #232d35;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer .items,
.footer .pages{
    margin-left: 90px;
}

.footer .block-item1,
.footer .block-item2,
.footer .block-item3 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  background-color: #EEE7CE;
  color: #145d56;
  text-align: center;
  width: 190px;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.footer .social {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  border-color: #00000000;
  border-radius: 90%;
}

.footer .title1,
.footer .title2,
.footer .title3 {
  color: #fff;
}

.footer .sub-head {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.footer .desc {
  color: #1D2A35;
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.692);
  font-weight: 450;
}

.footer .desc:hover {
  color: #2a5be0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body class="grid-container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="header-2">
        <ul>
          <p class="nameUser">Menú</p>
          <li class="list">
            <b></b>
            <b></b>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="uil uil-estate"></i>
              </span>
              <span class="title">Inicio</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list">
            <b></b>
            <b></b>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="uil uil-books"></i>
              </span>
              <span href="#" class="title">Explorar Libros</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list active">
            <b></b>
            <b></b>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="uil uil-question-circle"></i>
              </span>
              <span href="aboutOn" class="title">Acerca de</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <hr style="border: 2px solid #EEE7CE; border-radius: 2px; opacity: 1; width: 90%; margin-left: -2%; box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);">
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="toggle">
        <ion-icon name="menu-outline" class="open"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="close-outline" class="close"></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!----------- PIE DE PÁGINA ----------->
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="items d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="block-item1">
          <i class="uil uil-envelope" style="font-size: 250%; color: #145D56;"></i>
          <div class="sub-head">Email</div>
          <a href="mailto:bibliotecae.public2020@gmail.com" class="desc" style="font-size: 60%;">bibliotecae.public2020@gmail.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="block-item2">
          <i class="uil uil-clock" style="font-size: 250%; color: #f5b914;"></i>
          <div class="sub-head">Horarios</div>
          <a href="/aboutOn" class="desc" style="font-size: 75%;">Horarios de atención</a>
        </div>
        <div class="block-item3">
          <i class="uil uil-location-point" style="font-size: 250%; color: #D90E40;"></i>
          <div class="sub-head">Visitanos</div>
          <a href="ubicacion" class="desc" style="font-size: 75%;">Ubicación Biblioteca</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="bg-danger border-2 border-top border-color">
      <div class="pages d-flex justify-content-between p-4 pt-0 pb-0">
        <div>   
          <a href="/" class="title1">Inicio |</a>
          <a href="explorarLibros" class="title2">Explorar Libros |</a>
          <a href="aboutOn" class="title3">Acerca de</a>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary social" href="#!" role="button"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
      </div>
      <hr class="bg-danger border-2 border-top border-color">
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahhh bien entiendo. Gracias por la explicación y tomarte un tiempo para revisar el código.  Muy amable y atento!